# setState doen't update the score in counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, callback

Could you please help me to find a mistake in the callback function. So, I have an array of player objects. I also have a function in the Counter component that receives 2 parameters - index of a player and delta(+ 1 or - 1) depending on which button is pressed.

Initial state:

```
 state = {
    players: [
      {
        name: "Player 1",
        score: 0,
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "Player 2",
        score: 0,
        id: 2,
      },
      {
        name: "Player 3",
        score: 0,
        id: 3,
      },
      {
        name: "Player 4",
        score: 0,
        id: 4,
      },
    ],
  };
```

Player component:

```
const Player = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      <span
        <button
          onClick={() => props.removePlayer(props.id)}
        > Remove Player </button>
        {props.name}
      </span>

      <Counter
        score={props.score}
        index={props.index}
        changeScore={props.changeScore}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Counter component:

```
const Counter = (props) => {
  let index = props.index;

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => props.changeScore(index, -1)}> - </button>
      <span>{props.score}</span>
      <button
        onClick={() => props.changeScore(index, +1)}> + </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Function with a mistake:

```
  handleScoreChange = (index, delta) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      score: prevState.players[index].score + delta
    }));
  };
```

However it just doesn't work. Pressing - or + doesn't change the score of any player. All other things wok just fine and all props are passed correctly, the problem is somewhere is this code above...

- handleScoreChange is passed as a prop to Header and then to its child Counter with a name "changeScore" so mistake doesn't relate to the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just mutate state, try this instead:

```
handleScoreChange = (index, delta) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    players: prevState.players.map((player, i) =>
      index === i
        ? { ...player, score: player.score + delta }
        : player
    ),
  }));
};
```

Comment: It's not just the mutation part. @DmitryDev your original code is even changing the state shape which is wrong. Try HMR's suggestion

Comment: score: player.score + delta*, otherwise it's only incrementing

Answer (score 1):

i have created  a full working example like your code here it's:

```js
class Player extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.props.name}</span>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            this.props.changeScore(this.props.name, -1)
          }
        >
          {' '}
          -{' '}
        </button>
        <span>{this.props.score}</span>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            this.props.changeScore(this.props.name, +1)
          }
        >
          {' '}
          +{' '}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    players: [
      {
        name: 'Player 1',
        score: 0,
      },
      {
        name: 'Player 2',
        score: 0,
      },
      {
        name: 'Player 3',
        score: 0,
      },
      {
        name: 'Player 4',
        score: 0,
      },
    ],
  };

  handleScoreChange = (name, delta) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      players: prevState.players.map((player) => {
        if (player.name === name) {
          player.score += delta;
        }
        return player;
      }),
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.players.map((player) => (
          <Player
            key={player.name}
            {...player}
            changeScore={this.handleScoreChange}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-kalam-s7de4?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    players: [
      {
        name: "Player 1",
        score: 0
      },
      {
        name: "Player 2",
        score: 0
      },
      {
        name: "Player 3",
        score: 0
      },
      {
        name: "Player 4",
        score: 0
      }
    ]
  };
  handleScoreChange = (index, delta) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      players: [
        ...state.players.slice(0, index),
        { ...state.players[index], score: state.players[index].score + delta },
        ...state.players.slice(index + 1)
      ]
    }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.players.map((player, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div>{player.name}</div>
              <div>{player.score}</div>
              <button onClick={() => this.handleScoreChange(index, -1)}>
                -
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => this.handleScoreChange(index, 1)}>
                +
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. First of all, props.changeScore is correct because I pass like so changeScore={props.handleScoreChange} to the Header and then to its child Counter as a prop changeScore. That's why I have `onClick={() => props.changeScore(index, +1)}>`, should have described it better apparently. But why can't I modify state like this? On React official site there is a sample code `this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));`. Isn't it the same approach?

Comment: Ah I didn't realize since I didn't see your parent component; can you add the parent component to your question?

Comment: @DmitryDev You are [mutating](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md#value-vs-reference), if you don't understand that `object.someprop=newValue` mutates then please read the link. The react example I don't see an assignment to  a object property `state.counter + props.increment` doesn't change anything and it's result is assigned to `counter` which is a property of the new object: `{counter:value}` where `value` is `state.counter + props.increment `